# efficient mapping of very large dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two data frames `df1` and `df2` with the following columns:

```
A = ['id', 'a_id', 'c', 'd']
B = ['a_id', 'e', 'f']
```

For `a_id` in `df1` matching `a_id` in `df2`, I need to add `e` from `df2` to `df1` row. `Df1` is around 7 million rows and df2 is around 15k. I tried the code below but it takes too long. I was wondering if there's a better solution that could speed things up a bit and more memory efficient.

```
def map_df(row):
    for i, r in df2.iterrows():
        if row['a_id'] == r['a_id']:
            return row2['part_mean_correctness']

df1['e'] = df1.apply (lambda row: map_df(row), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I completely understood your issue but are you trying to do a [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)?
If so, then your code should just look like:

```py
import pandas as pd 
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a_id':[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'c': ["foo", "bar", "baz", "qux", "foobar"]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a_id':[3, 4], 'e': ["bar", "baz"]})
df1 = df1.merge(df2, on=["a_id"], how="left")
```

Then `df1` should look like

```
   a_id       c    e
0     1     foo  NaN
1     2     bar  NaN
2     3     baz  bar
3     4     qux  baz
4     5  foobar  NaN
```

Comment: That seems to have done the job. It merged both dataframes, mapping rows using a_id column.